# Vimeo Video player for flutter or api to get mp4 link

Tags: php, flutter, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

when i upload video to vimeo then i get the vimeo video link i can not play it on flutter video player so i tried to convert this link to mp4 using

```
**api.vimeo.com/{id}/config**
```

but it stopped to return video links this week , tried to contact vimeo but they send automatic reply
so after search i used another way from api vimeo

```
**https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{id}**
```

but same problem sometimes mp4 link not returned from vimeo video links

so i need flutter video player its able to play video using vimeo video link directly
or any way to get mp4 link to be able to run video on player

`

```
public function mp4_link($id)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/' . $id,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Accept: application/json',
                'Authorization: Bearer 111111111111111111',
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $response = (array) json_decode($response);
        curl_close($curl);

        if (!isset($response['files'])) {
            $response = Http::get("https://player.vimeo.com/video/$id/config");
            $response = (array) json_decode($response);
        }
        $response = [
            'pictures' => $response['pictures'] ?? $response['video']->thumbs ?? [],
            'duration' => $response['duration'] ?? 0,
            'files' => $response['files'] ?? $response['request']->files->progressive ?? []
        ];

        return $response;
    }
```

`

Answer (score 1):

There are several packages that can play vimeo videos in pub.dev. You can search and take a pick. But here are some, [pod_player](https://pub.dev/packages/pod_player) plays both YouTube and vimeo;
[vimeo_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/vimeo_player_flutter) ;

[vimeo_video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/vimeo_video_player)